# Go YAML parser failing silently

Tags: go, tags, yaml

I'm trying to get simple YAML parsing in go working with `gopkg.in/yaml.v2`.

From [the documentation](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2):

> Maps and pointers (to a struct, string, int, etc) are accepted as
>   out values. If an internal pointer within a struct is not 
>         initialized, the yaml package will initialize it if necessary 
>         for unmarshalling the provided data. The out parameter must not be nil.
>
> The type of the decoded values should be compatible with the 
>         respective values in out. If one or more values cannot be decoded 
>         due to a type mismatches, decoding continues partially until the 
>         end of the YAML content, and a *yaml.TypeError is returned with 
>         details for all missed values.

Note the important bits here:  "pointer within struct initialized if nec'y", and "yaml.TypeError returned if a value can't be decoded".

Now:

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type YamlTypeA struct {
    D string    `yaml: "d"`
    E string    `yaml: "e"`
}

type YamlTypeB struct {
    F string    `yaml: "f"`
}

type YamlTypeC struct {
    TypeA   *YamlTypeA      `yaml: "a"`
    TypeB   []YamlTypeB `yaml: "b"`
}

func main() {
    var yamlObj YamlTypeC

    text := []byte(`
---
a:  
   d: foo 
   e: bar
b: [{f: "fails"},
    {f: "completely"}]
`)

    err := yaml.Unmarshal(text,&yamlObj)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("OK")
    fmt.Printf("TypeA.D: %s\n", yamlObj.TypeA.D)
    fmt.Printf("I have %d TypeB\n", len(yamlObj.TypeB))
}
```

yields

```
 OK
 panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
 [signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x4014b3]
```

which appears to violate the promises made in the documentation jointly.  If I make the nested YamlTypeA immediate instead of a pointer, the result is that the output value is not touched, still no error:

```
 OK
 TypeA.D: 
 I have 0 TypeB
```

What gives here?   Is it just broken / poorly documented?  How can you get nested struct values to parse out of YAML?  (Using maps of maps is cumbersome and not at all a solution here.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have spaces in your struct tags, so they're being ignored:

```
type YamlTypeA struct {
    D string `yaml:"d"`
    E string `yaml:"e"`
}

type YamlTypeB struct {
    F string `yaml:"f"`
}

type YamlTypeC struct {
    TypeA *YamlTypeA  `yaml:"a"`
    TypeB []YamlTypeB `yaml:"b"`
}
```

Comment: Ugh.  Seriously?  Ugh.  Thanks.    That flag parsing is a Go rather than yaml thing, right?

Comment: (the "" to me seem to imply by convention/intuition/whatever that whitespace should not matter there.   Weird that I wrote the maps-of-maps test case without it, and it worked!)

Comment: Also, the documentation also seems to imply that tags are optional and the default yaml name is the down-cased field name:  "Struct fields are only unmarshalled if they are exported (have an upper case first letter), and are unmarshalled using the field name lowercased as the default key. Custom keys may be defined via the "yaml" name in the field tag: "    Doc bug, perhaps?  Or I guess "present and incorrect format" is different than not-present.

Comment: @BadZen: struct tags do work by the convention of the reflect package: http://play.golang.org/p/oOAeeqlQqn. I'm not sure if your case is supposed to work without tags, but that would be an issue to raise in github.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense.   After I thought about it for a moment, the fact that tags don't /have/ to be a:b (`reflect` convenience funcs just provide that convention) necessitates no white space.  Or syntactic ambiguity between "a: b" (two tags, not using convention) and "a: b" (one tag, using convention)!  So much for "intuition".